# How to Split many Strings with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

Let's say I have a bunch of strings which I get from user input. Each strings starts with a new line like the following example:

```
gordon:davis
harley:vona
empir:domen
furno:shyko
```

I would like to write a function in jQuery which loads the user data from the form and splits each row's sting. However I would ONLY need the first part of the strings, like:

```
gordon
harley
empir
furno
```

Is there any simple solution for this?

I have found something called: $.each(split) but I didn't get it work.

I'm sorry I'm a really newbie in Jquery, I hope you guys can help me out! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `String.prototype.split` method.

`"gordon:davis".split(":")` will return `["gordon","davis"]`

Based on this, using `Array.prototype.map` or a JQuery version :

```
var strings = ["gordon:davis", "harley:vona"];
var splitStrings = strings.map(function (string) {
    return string.split(":")[0];
});
```